# How to Copy Only selected Properties from Object A to Object B in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector

Since **Eye drop tool** coping all the properties from one object to another and I Don't want this in some cases.

Does any one knows **how to copy only selected property** form one object to another in illustrator.

### For example:

- Object A has a **fill color + outline**. And I want to to **copy Fill color (only)** and not the outline to Object B. Then what is the solution? Please help.
  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you **double-click the Eyedropper Tool** you can choose which items get picked up. It's a bit unreliable, and has a few bugs, but it does work in many cases.

You could also simply select Object A, drag the color from the Color Panel to the Swatch Panel, then select Object B and click the swatch you created to use that color.

---

Many have selected merely holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> and clicking with the Eyedropper tool. You *can* do that. However you should be aware that Shift-clicking with the Eyedropper tool picks up the **color used for the screen preview**. The Shift key picks up the **preview** color, not the *actual* color as it is applied to an object. The Shift-click method may not be one to use if you are trying to keep colors between objects the same.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could get an option list for the Eyedropper by double-clicking it :)

Comment: Thank you Scott. I was also not aware about that double clicking of Eyedropper tool have lots of options. Now I found the great Place to ask my doubts for IL. Actually I am just shifted from CorelDraw to IL so that I am facing lots of issue here in IL which i have to cover. This is great place. Thank you again :)

Comment: I didn't know you could drag a color to swatches. So simple, once you know it exists!

Answer (score 2):

Select the desired **stroke** or **fill** that you would like changed.
Select **Eyedropper tool**.
Hold **Shift + Click** on the new color.

Comment: simple and effective

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what scott wrote.

Using the eyedropper tool will apply all properties of the object selected (items that are selected when you doublt-click the eyedropper tool at least).

Another shortcut is to hold shift when picking the colour, that will only pick the colour clicked to the object selected, and will apply it to the active appearance at that moment (Stroke vs Fill).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes Mamoon your Shift+Eyedropper tool Trick really works for me even from the object which have gradient I can choose the color i want. Thanks!

One more thing if any one knows here ;). How to change the outline setting for individual objects (not for all objects in AI. only selected) so that when i increase or reduce object then outline also change accordingly.

Comment: Good to hear! Enjoy your colour picking!

Answer (score -1):

Shift+click doesn't work in CS6 (at least ont in 16.0.3). It just selects desired color but not applied it. I didn't find apply color function - i tried to click with different key combinations, click on color boxes, or on numeric value to go to edit mode and acknowledge value with enter key - nothing worked. Illustrator stays blind and deaf for user tries.
What works (beside changing eyedropper inner options):
1) shift+X to swap colors two times, doesn't work if two or more objects have different stroke or fill color (the one we are not interested to change).
2) copy color value from box, enter 0, enter again to the box, and paste copied value.

Many functions Illustrator has seems totally underdeveloped or badly thought and behaves much better in Inkscape or any other alternative editors. Real shame for such big player as Adobe.